# Number of subset

Tags: java, recursion, subset

```
class Solution {
    int f(int[] a, int s, int n) {
        if (n == 0)
            return s;
        return f(a, s + 1, n - 1) + f(a, s, n - 1);
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = { 1, 1, 2, 3 };
        System.out.println(new Solution().f(a, 0, a.length));
    }
}
```

I have written a code to print the number of subset, at every index I got two choices whether to include the a[i] in the subset or not for that I add 1 to s whenever the element is to be included, but this approach gives wrong answer. Why it is wrong?

Comment: why you no Math.pow(2, a.length) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.pow(2, a.length)
```

would be the obvious solution for that. but if you really want to find it that way it should 'return 1' instead of 'return s' since each time it arrives at zero, it means no element is left, thus empty list, thus 1.